# Control total del registro al crear/eliminar/editar subclaves en Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, registro-windows

Estoy intentando hacer que al dar click en un objeto (llamese imagen) se agregue un valor al registro de Windows, el punto es que sí funciona, sin embargo, necesito permisos para añadir una subclave.. explico:

```
 Imports Microsoft.Win32
Public Class Form1
Private Sub BotonAg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BotonAg.Click
    Dim h2 As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\heey")
    h2.SetValue("heey2", &H0)
    h2.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Es decir, en "Classes" no puedo crear una nueva subclave, no tengo los permisos suficientes. El código funciona perfectamente, sólo que no tengo permisos en **Classes** **¿Cómo puedo tomar todos los permisos? ¿Qué necesito agregar?**

Answer (score 1):

La solución que se me ocurre para tu problema es que le des **permisos de administrador a la aplicación.**

Con esto entonces no deberías tener problemas de Permisos en Editar el Registro de Windows.

Esto lo puedes hacer editando el archivo **app.manifest** del Proyecto.

Primero debes ir al menú **Propiedades** de tu Proyecto. (o en su defecto ubicar el archivo app.manifest desde el Explorador de Soluciones).

En las **Propiedades del Proyecto** debes tocar el botón "**Ver configuración de Windows**" del menú "Aplicación".

Luego reemplazar la linea que dice `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` por la que está comentada y dice **`<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Iba con todas las esperanzas, pero me temo que no ha funcionado.

He leido sobre esto: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.registrypermissionattribute.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.registrypermission.aspx

Pero, para serte sincera, no entiendo nada, no sé cómo agregar algo de lo que mencionan esos enlaces.

Comment: Tamara entonces estamos frente a un tipo de clase en el Editor de Registro un poco más difícil de acceder, confirmame: ¿puedes añadir una clase desde el Editor de Registros de Windows? (regedit). ¿La ventana de permisos de vuestra clase tiene habilitado como Propietario al usuario 'Administrador'? Ya he tenido experiencia con claves inaccesibles por lo que lamento comunicarte que tampoco he logrado una solución a nivel programación: simplemente algunas clases están lo suficientemente protegidas por lo que hay que darle permiso al Administrador para trabajar con ellas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ofrecerme tu ayuda. Si este mismo valor de registro lo agrego con un .bat, funciona perfectamente, lo único que hay que hacer en caso de no tener una cuenta administrador, sería ejecutarlo como tal. Directamente en regedit se puede agregar cualquier subclave sin problemas en "Classes" (en caso de ser administrador). Así que, no sé por qué no puedo acceder a ella por medio de vb (ya he accedido a ella en java, pero no lo uso debido a incompatibilidades de licencias)